# PPD locked in 16.04

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

When I run hp-check on my Ubuntu 16.04 (testing an Envy 7645), it reports that it can't open the ppd file in etc/cups/ppd.

It CAN open it if I run sudo hp-check.

The permissions for all three directories allow access down to the guest level, but the PPD file is apparently closed/invisible to all but ROOT.

The scanner function works just fine, and passes scanned documents to my Documents folder. But the printer is identified by the HP Devices tool as "idle." Most recently, I've sent two test pages to it. Nothing.

The version is HPLip-3.17.7, but I've had this problem ever since I upgraded to 3.17.# some months ago, and once it started, I had the problem with 3.16 as well. The printer works fine plugged into a Windows 7 machine.

Any ideas?

================== 
Update
Thanks to a response to a similar problem, I learned that the ppd file must be executable (chmod 754). This change made the printer work. However, another answer to a similar question advised installing hplip-data. Unfortunately I did that, and it hosed my Device Manager, a problem apparently I can only fix by reinstalled HPLip-3.17.7. maybe tomorrow.

The main lesson from all this is that HP's installer didn't set the correct permissions on the PPD file (which it also "couldn't find" until I located it manually right where you'd expect it to be), and has not done so for most of the 3.17 iterations. Moreover, once the PPD file is installed with the WRONG permissions, the old (3.16) installers fail to notice that and thus inherit the problem.

Second lesson: No more HP printers.